# What is B4TM4N SH3LL PHP WEBSHELL in linux server

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu

I recently noticed that in server a files is created by name bat.php, I downloaded the file and checked in local, it has some codes which i didnt understand and wondered what is this file and how it got generated in my server.
Can anyone tell me what is this? and why it is generated?

Comment: well, lets see it then?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone has compromised your security and installed a Web Shell script on your server. Here's the actual code! https://github.com/k4mpr3t/b4tm4n

Remove it NOW! This will allow the user to run CLI commands on your system!

Comment: OMG.. ok i have done already. what are the possible way? how he has entered into my server? i have followed all security and disabled most of the ports.

Comment: i would check for vulnerable php scripts that could allow code injection

Comment: I would wipe the server snd rebuild with latest builds and security fixes. Do not trust anything on the server or anything it can reach, like mounted filesystems.